# How do I read 通常版?

Tags: words, kanji, pronunciation, suffixes, rendaku

According to jisho.org, 通常 is pronounced as つうじょう.
I don't know how to pronounce 版 in 通常版. How is it pronounced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's つうじょう**ば**ん.

版【はん】 = version, edition

Although 版 is read as はん by itself, 版 in 通常版 would be read as ばん, due to [rendaku phenomenon](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/5010).

Answer (score 3):

**つうじょうばん**.

For some reason this kanji always exhibits rendaku voicing when in suffix environment. 通常版【つうじょうばん】, 限定版【げんていばん】 "limited edition", 保存版【ほぞんばん】 "collector's edition", 英語版【えいごばん】 "English version", キリシタン版【ばん】 "(Medieval Japan) Jesuit Mission presses" etc.

And as a counter-word:

- 1版 いっ**ぱん**
- 2版 に**はん**
- 3版 さん**ぱん** or さん**はん**
- 4版 よん**ぱん** or よん**はん**
- 5版 ご**はん**
- 6版 ろっ**ぱん** or ろく**はん**
- 7版 なな**はん**
- 8版 はっ**ぱん**
- 9版 きゅう**はん**
- 10版 じゅっ**ぱん** (or prescriptively じっぱん)