# What does the word 「すねぐれて」mean?

Tags: words, verbs

Here is the sentence including the word.

世を**すねぐれて**　十五年　孤児院ぐらしは身につかず

Is it a combination of 2 verbs between 「すねる」and 「ぐれる」?

I understand that 2 verbs can be combined with て-form　of the first one.

**Extra question:** Why is it not 「暮｛く｝らし」instead of「ぐらし」?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost certainly it's from すねる + ぐれる. Because there is no in-between て, すねぐれる sounds like it's an established compound verb (such as 飛び起きる, こぼれ落ちる, 遊び呆ける), but I haven't seen this combination before.

From what I could google, it probably is a rare dialect word used in the eastern part of Japan.

[This page](http://www1.tmtv.ne.jp/~kadoya-sogo/ibaraki-su.html) lists すねぐれる as an 茨城弁 term.

> すねぐれる
>   【動】拗ねる、ひねくれる

There are a very few actual occurrences of すねぐれる/拗ねぐれる in some sites, for example:

- http://maron0707.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-630.html

  > ルークはマロンに対して「うなる」事はしないんですけど、待ちきれなくなると実力行使で、お膝に割り込んで来る事が多いです。昨日は割り込んできて、私に「あっ、ダメだよ」って軽く言われたので、**すねぐれ**モードになりました（＾＾；）
- http://m-pe.tv/u/m/novel/?uid=kukyosoka&id=1&act=viewPage&p=2&CID=11&PHPSESSID=edhoqt2bgk91koeiam6k7covh1

  > 「そんなに俺が嫌いかっ？　嫌いなのかっ？　嫌いなんだなっ？　す、**すねぐれて**やるーッ！」（勢い良く飛び出す）

And there are at least three native speakers who wondered what すねぐれる means, just like you.

- http://alfirin.jugem.jp/?eid=381

  > ところで。「すねぐれる」という単語は全国一般的に使われている標準語なんでしょうか…。私、九州、中国、関西、東北地方には住んだことがありますが聞いたことない。高永さんの漫画には時々知らない言葉が出てくるんだよなー。
- http://fujoshina.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2007/01/__0f3d.html

  > それから「すねぐれる」って言葉も可愛いと思いました。これ方言なんでしょうか？それとも標準語？気になったので調べてみました。昔の茨城弁やあらかわ弁にあるみたいです。うーん、関係ないのかな？でも響きが可愛いです。すねぐれる。
- http://s.webry.info/sp/39cat.at.webry.info/200909/article_2.html

  > 「出発前に、金太郎は「すねぐれ」ておりました・・・どうぞよろしくお願いします」とあり
  >   「すねぐれ？」なんて可愛いネーミング！久々に私の中でヒットしました。

---

As for your extra question, it's [a simple result of 連濁 phenomenon](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/5010). ～ぐらし is relatively common (eg, その日暮らし, 一人暮らし).