# Many subject and topic particles in the same sentence

Tags: particles

I'm new here but had some trouble finding this so I am going to ask.

Is it OK to have more than one は or が particles in the same sentence, I've realized that in cases that there is a comma it is OK because the sentence is fragmented but I have no clue in cases where there no comma.for instance the sentence "I don't like people who like fish". I have come with three ways to write it and Google translator have the same translation for the 3 of them bUT I feel that only one is right:

1.私は魚が好きな人が好きじゃない

2.私は魚好きな人が好きじゃない

3.私は魚好きな人すきじゃない

For some reason I fell the third one is the correct, so I ask you, which one is the correct and why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK to have two or more が/は in one sentence, and this typically happens when a *relative clause* is involved, like in this case. (I think you know the basics of relative clauses, but here's a good starter: [Relative Clauses and Sentence Order](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/clause))

> 1. 私は魚が好きな人が好きじゃない。
> 2. 私は魚好きな人が好きじゃない。
> 3. 私は魚好きな人好きじゃない。

These all make sense, and carry the same meaning.

But Sentence 3 sounds blunt and a bit unnatural to me. While simple particles like が/は tend to be omitted in simple sentences in casual conversations, a longer noun clause like 魚好きな人 ("people who like fish") tends to be explicitly marked with some particle. Otherwise, the sentence would be hard to parse.

> - 本読んだ。 (okay in casual conversations)
> - [?] 友達に借りた厚くて難しい本読んだ。 (makes sense, but を is usually expected after 本)

And also note that `好【ず】き` after a noun is [almost considered as a suffix ("-phil", "lover")](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%A5%BD%E3%81%8D-1), so Sentence 2 looks okay simply because 魚【さかな】好【ず】き sounds like one na-adjective. Note that 好き is read as ずき due to [rendaku](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/5010).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give the links a read and study more! ありがとうございます!

Answer (score 0):

The correct translation is 1.

> 私は魚が好きな人が好きじゃない。

私は(noun)が好きじゃない and the (noun) is 人 which has been modified by 魚が好きな.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that every noun in a sentence need either a topic or subject particle?

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Absolutely not.  Nouns can be objects marked with を, or they can be linked to another noun via の, and so on.  There are a lot of other roles nouns can play.  (And you can mark other things with は, not just nouns.)