# Correct grammar for "snow fox"?

Tags: grammar, words, definitions

I looked up in translator that "Snow fox" is gonna be "Yuki no kitsune". Ok, yuki - snow, kitsune - fox. But what if I get rid of "no" part? What if I spell it like "Yuki kitsune" or "Kitsune yuki". Would it mean the same? Or is it just going to be two separate words?

I want to know specifically about "Yuki kitsune" and "Kitsune yuki" examples, but it raises the question about usage of "no" particle.

Comment: "Kitsune yuki" sounds like a fried tofu served on a plate of snow ;-)

Comment: We have snow foxes or something like them here in Hokkaido, we call them キタキツネ

Answer (score 4):

If you're referring to [arctic fox (*Vulpes lagopus*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arctic_fox), which seems to be also known as snow fox, its Japanese name is [ホッキョクギツネ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9B%E3%83%83%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A7%E3%82%AF%E3%82%AE%E3%83%84%E3%83%8D) (ホッキョク = 北極 = the Arctic).

If you are only vaguely looking for a Japanese word which "sounds like snow fox", I would suggest ユキギツネ (yuki **g**itsune) instead of ユキキツネ (yuki **k**itsune). Although there seems to be no real species called ユキギツネ, this sounds realistic enough, and it may be used, for example, as the name of an enemy in a fantasy game. Many real foxes are named ○○ギツネ (○○ **g**itsune, without *no*) in Japanese. See this question regarding why キ needs to be voiced: [Rules or criteria for 連濁: Voiced or unvoiced syllables in compound words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/5010)

Unsurprisingly, キツネユキ sounds like "fox snow" or "fox-like snow", which makes little sense to me.

Comment: If I understood correctly, if I use Yuki(雪) as a name and add Kitsune(狐). Then it will be ｷ not ｷﾞ right?

Comment: そういえば雪うさぎが珍しく逆（実態は雪）なのちょっとおもしろいですね．

Comment: @Alyx What do you mean? Something like "Rudolph the reindeer" where "Rudolph" is a proper noun? Then you have to say "狐の雪" (≒ *kitsune no Yuki* ≒ "Yuki the fox").

Comment: @naruto No, I meant 雪狐 as a proper noun, as it was about 美空 in the link that you gave. Which is, I thought, going to mean the name and "snow fox" at the same time... well, something like wordplay. Also  I didn't noticed comments at first and I've read there that rendaku is optional .-.

Comment: @Alyx *Fox* may be a common proper noun in English (eg, Michel J Fox), but 狐 is not common as a proper noun in Japanese. And whether rendaku is used is often unpredictable in proper nouns. For example 中田 is a common family name, but you can't tell if it's *Nakata* or *Nakada* only by the kanji. That said, if I encountered a fictional character whose name is 雪狐 in kanji, I would probably guess it's read either *yuki-gitsune* (with rendaku) or *setsu-ko* (with on-yomi).