# When is 酒 pronounced sake and when is it pronuounced saka? And why?

Tags: readings

Saka as in 酒場{さかば} or zaka as in 居酒屋{いざかや}

Sake as in 酒{さけ}

Comment: I think you mistyped the furigana there in 酒場（さかば）

Comment: Oops you are right. I have edited it. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can find a good answer here: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/rules-or-criteria-for-%E9%80%A3%E6%BF%81-voiced-or-unvoiced-syllables-in-compound-words

Comment: I do understand the need for 連濁 but isn't 連濁 for the beginning of the first consonant of the latter component?

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between saka and zaka, or the difference between sake and saka?

Comment: The latter. I have edited the question to make it clearer. Sorry if it was unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between さか and ざか is just one of rendaku, which I think is well discussed here: [Rules or criteria for 連濁: Voiced or unvoiced syllables in compound words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/rules-or-criteria-for-%E9%80%A3%E6%BF%81-voiced-or-unvoiced-syllables-in-compound-words)

The reason that 酒{さけ} becomes 酒{さか} in some cases is not really directly related to rendaku（連濁）rather this is called ten'on（転音）.

Just as a short answer, some words, when part of a compound word, will have a change in the vowel sound of the final syllable/mora.

This change seems to sometimes carry the implication of「何々**の為の**何々」.

> え turning into あ:

- 酒{さけ}の場{ば} ⇒ 酒場{さかば}
- 手{て}の綱{つな} ⇒ 手綱{たづな}
- 雨{あめ}の戸{と} ⇒ 雨戸{あまど}

> い turning into う

- 神{かみ}の主{ぬし} ⇒ 神主{かむぬし} ⇒ 神主{かんぬし}
- 口{くち}の輪{わ} ⇒ 轡{くつわ}

> い turning into お

- 木の陰　木陰

You can see other examples here:
http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12109076097

The best Japanese reference I can find that really concisely outlines what's going on with さけ・ざけ・さか・ざか is this one here:
http://www.nihongokyoshi.co.jp/manbow/manbow.php?id=845&TAB=2

Comment: The historical evidence actually suggests the opposite -- the original form was `/saka/`, while `/sake/` was a later innovation.  Some writers (possibly including Shibatani in his [*The Languages of Japan*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sD-MFTUiPYgC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)) suggest that the vowels were fronted (`/a/` → `/e/`, `/o/` or `/u/` → `/i/`) through a fusion with the ancient emphatic nominal particle い{i}. I've also read somewhere that Ainu *kamuy* is possible evidence of this: ancient *kamu* + *i* → *kamui*, then the final *-ui* becoming *-i* in modern *kami*.

Comment: So too with *saka* + *i* → *sakai* → *sake*.  We see similar monophthongization (where two-vowel sounds become one-vowel sounds) in modern slangy Japanese, such as *sugoi* becoming *sugē*, *takai* becoming *takē*, etc.