# Japanese term for weight gained in a loving relationship?

Tags: set-phrases, phrases, phrase-requests

I came across this phrase in reading a few weeks ago, and can't for the life of me find the note I made on it.

It refers to plumpness in a positive sense, reaching a comfortable state of gained weight that you only find after a while in a really good, sweet relationship.

Hope someone else knows what I'm talking about!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for [幸せ太り](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%B9%B8%E3%81%9B%E5%A4%AA%E3%82%8A) (pronounced as しあわせ**ぶ**とり due to [rendaku](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/5010)).

This word is not particularly positive nor negative/derogatory. Gaining weight itself is not a desirable thing, but some people may see it as an enviable evidence of happiness.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Does the しあわせ not give it a positive connotation?

Comment: @araihada Yes, but 太る is usually negative. The final connotation depends on how you use the word.

Comment: @araihada, reminds me a bit of the similar English phrase_"fat and happy"_, which could be a positive or a negative depending on how it's used.