# ロンドン橋落ちた is pronounced はし or ばし?

Tags: pronunciation, song-lyrics

ロンドン橋落ちた (London bridge is falling down) is pronounced はし or ばし?

I heard this from a girl singing in the Guilty Crown episode 1 (8:30 mark). When I went to look it up, Google translate and ichi.moe say 橋 is はし but I'm pretty sure I hear a "b" in the song like they're singing ばし, and I think [Google translate pronounces "b"](https://translate.google.com/?sl=ja&tl=en&text=%E3%83%AD%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%83%B3%E6%A9%8B%E8%90%BD%E3%81%A1%E3%81%9F&op=translate) in the full line too.

Is this just how a `は` sounds like after a `ん`? Is it just this phrase? Am I mishearing?

Comment: Relevant previous questions: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/rules-or-criteria-for-%e9%80%a3%e6%bf%81-voiced-or-unvoiced-syllables-in-compound-words https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69516/why-is-katakana-not-pronounced-katagana/69519#69519

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for those links Ringil and Naruto. To have an answer here:

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku

> Rendaku (連濁, Japanese pronunciation: [ɾendakɯ], lit. "sequential voicing") is a phenomenon in Japanese morphophonology that governs the voicing of the initial consonant of a non-initial portion of a compound or prefixed word.

> ひと + ひと → ひと-びと
> hito + hito → hitobito ("person" + "person" → "people")

So I guess that's what's happening here. The second part of the compound is はし and is pronounced ばし. And the rules about this Rendaku are complicated.