# 働きづめ or 働きずめ? Where does that suffix come from?

Tags: words, pronunciation

While playing a game, one of the characters said (the text is in English and the voice is in Japanese):

- 君はずっと働きずめだったから、今日はもう寝な。

My conjecture is that the correct written form is 働きずめ, but is that correct? Is it 働きづめ or 働きずめ? Moreover, are there any other words constructed with that same suffix?

Comment: Relevant: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/69516/why-is-katakana-not-pronounced-katagana/69519#69519

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not correct.

When you break that down, it's 働{はたら}き+詰{つ}め. So, it must be with つ+濁点{だくてん}(゛) - づ.

The method is called 連濁{れんだく}. I'll leave the explain to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) and question/answer that I linked in comment at OP.

There's much more like this one, such as:

- 生{い}き辛{づら}い = 生{い}きる+辛{つら}い
- 磯釣{いそづ}り = 磯{いそ}+釣{つ}り
- 折{お}り鶴{づる} = 折{お}り+鶴{つる}
- 寿司詰{すしづ}め = 寿司{すし}+詰{づ}め

Comment: Okay, now I know it's spelled as 働きづめ, thanks. But 連濁 was not my point. What I asked would be, then, if there are any other words of the form V + 詰め.

Comment: @ElizabethMiddleford The examples in [this link](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%A9%B0_%28%E3%81%A5%E3%82%81%29/#jn-148300) are all づめ. As a post-masu-stem suffix, 働きづめ should be the most common, but it can attach to a few other verbs.

Comment: 「さしずめ」（差し詰め） may be special, being an established adverb, perhaps?

Comment: @Chocolate According to [goo](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%B7%AE%E8%A9%B0%E3%82%81/) ずめ/づめ they both are fine I think? Still, most of time we write that in hiragana, and I think I've never seen さしずめ written as さしづめ except dictionary/old article, so...

Comment: According to [this](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%9B%9B%E3%81%A4%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D), the distinctions are ultimately fuzzy. 現代仮名遣いでは、複合語であるなどの語源意識が残っており、「ち」「つ」などから生じたことが明らかである場合に「ぢ」「づ」を用いることになっているが、語源意識が残っているかどうかを客観的に定めることは難しく、どうしても主観的にならざるを得ない（中略）「現代仮名遣い」では、「世界中」「稲妻」などの一部の語は、「じ」「ず」で書くことを本則とし、「ぢ」「づ」で書くことも許容するという方針が打ち出された

Comment: If you can read/understand it, [this blog post](https://mtoyoshi.hateblo.jp/entry/20080613/1213410155) is very interesting. quote: 小学生が学校のテストで「地面」を「ぢめん」と書いて×にされてしまった。先生になぜ「じめん」と書くのかを質問したところ先生がたじたじになり「それは決まりだから」と答えてしまった、というものだ。 --  他にも「大詰め」と「差詰め」も、歴史的仮名遣いの場合だと「詰（つ）める」だから「おおづめ」「さしづめ」と書いていた。しかしながら現代かなづかいでは「おおづめ」と「さしずめ」らしい。 ... They're EXTREMELY fuzzy!

Comment: Actually, there's no difference between the pronunciation of ず and づ nowadays so Japanese people often refer to づ as「つにてんてん」(つ with dots)

Comment: @puhitaku I thought we were talking about Yomigana not pronunciation?

Comment: @Skye-AT It's just FYI sry

Comment: @puhitaku No worries :)