# Reading of the jukugo 友達

Tags: readings

I am new to the Japanese language and I have been wondering why the word 友達 is read as 'tomodachi' instead of 'tomotachi' even though its pronunciation is kun-kun (tomo-dachi) but the kun-yomi of 達 is 'tachi'. Is there any specific reason to this ? Thanks.

Comment: related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/rules-or-criteria-for-連濁-voiced-or-unvoiced-syllables-in-compound-words

Comment: Welcome to Japanese.StackExchange! your question is probably answered in the link posted above by @JACK (check the answer directly [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/2529/32952)). Feel free to be more specific in your question if you think it is not solved by the provided link.