# Rendaku (連濁) in graffiti?

Tags: readings, rendaku

I was wondering about the reading of 糞社会 in the graffiti in this image:

[image]

ふんしゃかい
or
ふんじゃかい?

There does not seem to be an easy way to know, as the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) tells us:

> In modern Japanese, rendaku is common but at times unpredictable, with certain words unaffected by it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is くそしゃかい.

Rendaku is never applied to 社会. 社会 is a kango (Chinese-origin on-reading word), which normally resists rendaku. See: [Rules or criteria for 連濁: Voiced or unvoiced syllables in compound words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/5010)

Besides, the reading of this 糞 is くそ, not ふん. くそ is a derogatory word analogous to English "shit(ty)" or "crap(py)". 糞 read as ふん is more of a technical term meaning "feces (of animal/insect)".