# Given harakiri was once pronounced farakiri and, even earlier, parakiri, how do I write those two older forms, using kanjis?

Tags: kanji, history

In ["The Unfolding Of Language" by Guy Deutscher](https://www.penguin.co.nz/books/the-unfolding-of-language-9781407070285), I've read that "harakiri" was once pronounced as "farakiri" and, even earlier "parakiri", thus reavaling the word underwent the *p → f → h* weakening shift that happened in many languages.

Now, from a simple we search, I found that *harakiri* is written like 腹切り.

What about the other two forms? How do I write them?

Comment: The 腹 in 腹切り is not a phonetic representation in the first place. Are you familiar with Japanese writing systems?

Comment: What is your goal? Discussion itself about features of phonology or grammar of older stages of Japanese? Writing some text in archaic spelling / style? Something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you asked this question knowing almost nothing about the [Japanese writing system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_writing_system), you should read a bit about it first. 腹切り is a perfectly valid Japanese word, but it's written using a type of character called [kanji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji), which are **ideograms**. 腹 is a character that represents the meaning of "abdomen", and 切 is an ideogram that means "cut". Although the kanji 腹 has several standard readings including "hara", you cannot use kanji to explain the pronunciation of a word. As an analogy, you can use the emoji  to convey the meaning of cat, and it has a standard reading (/kæt/), but you cannot use this character to explain the historical pronunciations of the word. Even if it was *pronounced* differently in the past,  is always *written* as .

If you want to compare various pronunciations of a word, you need to use [**hiragana**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana) instead, which are phonetic characters similar to the Latin alphabet. Here's how you can simulate the old pronunciations of "harakiri" using hiragana:

| Romaji (Latin) | Hiragana |
| --- | --- |
| harakiri | はらきり |
| farakiri | ふぁらきり |
| parakiri | ぱらきり |

Note that the latter two rows are just rough simulations. No one would understand you if you pronounced or wrote this word in these old ways.

(By the way, the word-initial "p" sound in Japanese words disappeared before the 8th century, and the practice of harakiri did not appear until the 12th century. I doubt that people in the past actually pronounced it like "parakiri".)

Comment: From the link you provided I understand that _らきり_ maps to _rakiri_, so how comes _ha_ and _pa_ correspond to _は_ and _ぱ_, i.e. 1 character, whereas _fa_ needs 2, _ふぁ_ (the former of which at that page is associated to _fu_, the latter... don't know)?

Comment: Another side question. If 切=cut + 腹=abdomen = 切腹=seppuku, what is the り in 腹切り? I mean, it looks like り is a hiragana, so it maps to _ri_, whichi is indeed the final sound of _harakiri_, but how come it's needed, given that 腹切 would already represent the idea of "abdomen cut"?

Comment: @Enlico ふぁ is an "extended kana" used to approximate foreign sounds. See [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19226/5010) (note that it uses katakana instead of hiragana). Since the "fa" sound disappeared more than 1000 years ago, we don't have a one-character hiragana for that sound. Instead, we use ふぁ . As for this り, please search for "okurigana".

Comment: @Enlico You may be interested in [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/94359/5010).

Comment: From [wikipedia's page on Okurigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okurigana) I would have thought that り in 腹切り is what is mentioned in the _Multi-character words_ section, which doesn't seem to refer to conjugation. Probably this a rabbit hole, given my 0 knowledge of the language, ahah.

Comment: @Enlico I can't answer endless questions from someone who is merely curious, but this り is the [ren'yōkei](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65953/5010) of a [godan verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_conjugation#Verb_bases), [used as a noun](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010). In other words, 切る means "cut" and 切り roughly means "cutting".