# What's the rule behind the change of the pronunciation of '薬' in '目薬'?

Tags: pronunciation

目薬 is pronounced 'めぐすり' while 薬 'くすり'.
The pronunciation of '薬' change from 'くすり' to 'ぐすり'. What's the rule behind this change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rules or criteria for 連濁: Voiced or unvoiced syllables in compound words](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2526/rules-or-criteria-for-%e9%80%a3%e6%bf%81-voiced-or-unvoiced-syllables-in-compound-words)

Answer (score 4):

This is [rendaku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku) (連濁) which commonly occurs in compounds in Japanese. Unfortunately, in general whether it applies or not isn't at all predictable. However, there are tendencies including the well-known [Lyman's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku#Lyman%27s_Law) which at least tells you where it *cannot* occur.